# applicationDidEnterBackground - How to save my user data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

A novice's question.

I have one NotePageAppDelegate and one NotePageViewController. Simple. In my ViewController, I have defined a method to save the user data. It works perfectly if I click a button in my app which calls the method saveToDisk which is defined in my ViewController.

```
    -(IBAction) saveToDisk
{ // saves the file to the disk
}
```

This works perfectly if I click my button. However, if I close the app (i.e. in the Simulator clicking the Home Button), I would like to automatically save the page. I thought this is rather straight forward, so I put this in my AppDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    NotePageViewController* controller = [NotePageViewController alloc];

    [controller saveToDisk]; 

    [controller release];

}
```

However, this has no effect whatsoever. Have I forgotten to define something else? Or should this theoretically do the job if I press the Home Button in the Simulator?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm surprised that doesn't crash, since you're calling a method on an uninitialized instance.

You have the right idea, but you should be calling `saveToDisk` on an instance of the controller that *already exists*, not creating a new one that probably has no user modifications.

Comment: @Anomie: Well, it doesn't crash. Hmm.. sorry to bother with this question, but which instance of the controller already exists? How do I get one into existence? In the header file? Should I do the alloc there?

Comment: @n.evermind: You probably already have one on the screen, don't you? That's the one that you need. It might already be stored as a property on your application delegate or something along those lines; without seeing any code, I can only guess.

Comment: @Anomie: Yes, well, I have a NotePageViewController.xib which is on my screen. But I guess this isn't what you mean. Which part of the code would you need to see? AppDelegate header / main or ViewController header / main?

Comment: @Anomie: This is the AppDelegate.h: `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class NotePageViewController;

@interface NotePageAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    NotePageViewController *viewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NotePageViewController *viewController;

@end` and this is the ViewController.h

Comment: @Anomie: `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NotePageViewController : UIViewController {
 IBOutlet UILabel *pageCount;
 IBOutlet UITextView *TVnote;
*prevButton;IBOutlet UIButton *saveButton;IBOutlet UIButton *deleteButton;
 NSMutableArray *NoteBook;
 NSString *OneNote;
 NSUInteger currentPageCounter;
 //NotePage *currentPage;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *pageCount;
...
-(IBAction) nextPage;
-(IBAction) prevPage;
-(void) savePage;
-(IBAction) saveToDisk;
-(IBAction) delPage;


-(void) syncCounter;
-(void) syncTextView;



@end`

Comment: @n.evermind: Unless you have things hooked up wrong in the nib, it's right there on your app delegate in the `viewController` property.

Comment: @Anomie: Thanks... sorry for such stupid questions. So I guess all I need to do is to call [NotePageViewController saveToDisk];  in my applicationDidEnterBackground then, right? If I do so, however, I get the warning that my ViewController may not respond to 'saveToDisk'... do I need to change it from -(void)saveToDisk to +(void)saveToDisk?

Comment: @n.evermind: No, you would call `[self.viewController saveToDisk]`. OTOH, if you *can* change it to `+(void)saveToDisk` that would also work.

Comment: Thanks... I see, it works perfectly now. My problem was that I didn't realise that my NotePageViewController is loaded into the viewController and that I can call methods in my NotePageViewController by calling viewController... makes perfect sense. Sorry to have annoyed you and thank you so much for helping out!